# Long-untouched ASP.NET app throws "Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'" after Server 2008 security updates

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an app that has been running for years on a .NET 3.5 targeted ASP.NET application.

Last night a slew of overdue updates hit its web server (Windows 2008, IIS7), and now the app doesn't work.

The app fails when trying to connect to an Access database (via standard built in libraries; nothing third party in play here), and the error message is:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll

I've googled this extensively and the advice is always the same: repair/reinstall .NET Framework.

I have done this; I did full uninstall and re-install of Framework 3.5 and 4.5.  No help.
Copying the two EnterpriseServices DLLs into the web site app's BIN folder did not help either.

I did some digging in Process Explorer but am not an expert in that app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is a viable long term solution, but just wanted to update that rolling back the security patches resulted in the app working again.  It was one of these four:

Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows XP, Server 2003, Vista and Server 2008 for x64 (KB2861697)

Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows XP, Server 2003, Vista, and Server 2008 for x64 (KB2604111)

Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows XP, Server 2003, Vista, and Server 2008 for x64 (KB2736416)

Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows XP, Server 2003, Vista, and Server 2008 for x64 (KB2840629)